# Unable to extend partition with gdisk on XenServer 6.5

Tags: linux, partition, xenserver, fdisk

I'm having trouble extending my partition on a XenServer 6.5.  I originally had a 1.4TiB device (hardware RAID5) that I since upgraded to 10.9TiB.  I upgraded the RAID by swapping out one disk at a time until the 4 disks were replaced.

I then used the RAID configuration to extend the RAID to the full 10.9TiB size.

```
=> ctrl slot=4 ld all show status
   logicaldrive 1 (10.9 TB, 5): OK
```

I've next told Xen dom to rescan the scsi device:

```
echo 1 >  /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
```

Now when I start gdisk, I see the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 23441913520 sectors, 10.9 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): A28B730F-3064-494E-BD7E-DDE8CAD5A12D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 2930122766
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 6042 sectors (3.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         8388641   4.0 GiB     0700  
   2         8390656        16777249   4.0 GiB     0700  
   3        16779264      2930122766   1.4 TiB     8E00
```

So I see that `gdisk` is able to see the full 10.9TiB, but I can't seem to delete and recreate parititon 3 to be larger than the original 1.4TiB.  Furthermore, it says `last usable sector is 2930122766`.

How can I get gdisk to allow me to create a partition that goes from sectors 16779264-23441913520?

Comment: Try to use parted, it can expand partition without deleting it. Do you use LVM on `/dev/sda3`?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy - Sadly, I can't seem to find an rpm package parted for XenServer 6.5 (based on CentOS 5).  But I still do not understand why gdisk won't allow me to extend beyond the maximum value of the original disk.

Comment: And what about LVM?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy - Sorry... Yes it is an LVM partition.

Comment: LVM is used only for virtual machines or for Xen system partitions also?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy It's just for the VMs (as far as I know).  At this point, I gave up though.  I finally managed to find a version of parted that worked.  It complained about bad location of a GPT table so moved it.  Then I was able to resize.  But I had to reboot for the system to recognize the new partition defn.  But when I did, it seems to have messed with the boot loader b/c I couldn't boot from the drive anymore.  In the end I gave up and reinstalled Xen on top of it again.  Fixed my boot loader.

Comment: It's a strange, because root partition wasn't on LVM.  I think you could resize partition without reboot via `gdisk` after stopping all virtual machines and​ LVM volume group.

Comment: ```o create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
```, I just came across this issue, but it's late so i did fdisk then back to gdisk to force a new gpt... but "o" would have worked. (for those with multiple partitions i'd use sgdisk)

Answer (score 9):

Let gdisk verify the disk for problems (key `v`).

In my case it identified:

```
The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e' option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition table's locations.
```

I used `x` `e`.

Then `m`(ain menu) `p` showed the "last usable sector" as expected.

Comment: Just as a note to others: The answer is in no way XenServer specific.